# How to force a regex to be as conservative as possible when some elements are optional?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have some strings like this:

```
ex_1 = "03/09     03/09      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF     47AJ    1234    250.00"
ex_2 = "          03/10      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF             1234    98.00"
ex_3 = "03/09     03/09      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF             1234    50.00"
lines = [ex_1, ex_2, ex_3]
```

The strings above are aligned to represent what they look like in the original PDF, but the number of spaces between any of the elements can vary. As you can see, the first and fourth elements can be missing, but not necessarily both at the same time. The goal is to extract all of these elements, even if they're not present, and put them into a `pandas.DataFrame`.

My approach has been to use regex, which is working for the most part. This is what I'm using:

```
data = []
regex = r"((?:\d\d/\d\d\s+)?)(\d\d/\d\d\s+)(.*?\s+)((?:[0-9A-Za-z]{1,5}\s+)?)((?:\d{1,5}\s+)?)((?:-?\d+,?)*\.\d\d)"
for line in lines:
  match = re.search(regex, line)
  if match:
    elems = match.groups()
    data.append(elems)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following output:

```
[("03/09", "03/09", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF", "47AJ", "1234", "250.00"),
 ("", "03/10", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF", "1234", "", "98.00"),
 ("03/09", "03/09", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE", "REF", "1234", "50.00")
]
```

The above is wrong for indices 1 and 2. In `data[1]`, `"1234"` should be the 4th index and `""` should be the third. In `data[2]`, `"58AM"` should not be part of the third element and should be the 4th element with `"1234"` being the 5th element.

The output should look like this:

```
[("03/09", "03/09", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF", "47AJ", "1234", "250.00"),
 ("", "03/10", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF", "", "1234", "98.00"),
 ("03/09", "03/09", "ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF", "", "1234", "50.00")
]
```

So my question is how do I tell the regex that it's possible that that 4th element might be missing, but needs to be accounted for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe in this particular case regexes are an overkill. Just use `split()` to split on whitespace.  In any case I believe the `\s+` should be *outside* the optional `?` group, so that the spaces are matched when the element is not present. This may even solve your problem.

Comment: @Bakuriu But what about the text in the third element? In the example they're all the same, but in practice that won't be true and I won't know how many elements there will be. I know that in the end I need to have 6 elements in my tuple, but if I split on white space and there are 8 elements, then I won't know if I need to combine 3 of them into the 3rd element, or 5 of them because element 1 and 4 are blank, or whatever other permutations exist. I thought about doing that, but it's more hurtful than helpful.

Comment: @Bakuriu That seems simple enough, but I get this as the first element of the output: `['03/09', '', '   03/09      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF     47AJ    1234 ', '', '', '250.00']`

Comment: I've added an answer. I've tested with the three sample inputs you provided and it works. Looking at the output you got you may have used the wrong value for `maxsplit` or used `line` instead of `rest` when doing the `rsplit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me (python 3.4):

```
import re

ex_1 = "03/09     03/09      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF     47AJ    1234    250.00"
ex_2 = "          03/10      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF             1234    98.00"
ex_3 = "03/09     03/09      ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF             1234    50.00"
lines = [ex_1, ex_2, ex_3]

data = []
regex = r"(\d\d/\d\d)?\s+(\d\d/\d\d)\s+([A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)*)\s+([0-9A-Za-z]{1,5})?\s+(\d{1,5})\s+(-?[\d,]+\.\d\d)"
for line in lines:
    match = re.search(regex, line)
    if match:
        elems = match.groups()
        data.append(elems)
```

I get this output

```
data = [('03/09', '03/09', 'ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF', '47AJ', '1234', '250.00'),
        (None, '03/10', 'ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF', None, '1234', '98.00'),
        ('03/09', '03/09', 'ACH CREDIT BALANCE REF', None, '1234', '50.00')]
```

Basically I moved your `\s+`'s outside the groups, and only made those groups that are optional, optional. You also had some nested groups that were unnecessary.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: This wasn't in the original question, but what if the 5th element was also optional? There's no way to tell the regex to give more importance to the 5th element than to the 4th element is there? What I mean is that the regex looks and finds that only one of the two optional elements is there, so it puts it in the 4th element and makes the 5th element `None`. Is there anyway to tell it to satisfy the 5th element first?

Comment: You could make the regex more specific (4th group requires a letter, 5th has no letters) which would differentiate, or you could make the `\s+` before the 4th group non-greedy by using `\s+?` instead. This will match the fewest spaces possible instead of the most.

Comment: Making the space before the 4th group non-greedy did the trick. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution is simply:

```
for line in lines:
    first, second, rest = line.split(maxsplit=2)
    res = rest.rsplit(maxsplit=3)
    data.append((first, second) + res)
```

This avoids splitting the spaces in the third element by first performing only the first two splits, and then splitting for three times *from the right*.